# Arrows, Backspace, Editing Problems When Connected to SunOS From MacOS

Tags: ssh, terminal, solaris, macos

I cannot edit the **PATH=** line in .profile in vim. In Insert mode, I press home or end and it shows *F^?*. I press arrow-right a few times and VIM shows below:

```
C
C
C
C
```

I am using this machine/OS:

```
SunOS hostname 5.10 Generic_150400-14 sun4v sparc SUNW,Netra-T5440
```

Also the home and end keys do not navigate the command line, and neither do delete or backspace work. Delete changes the capitalization of each character until it reaches the end of the line, and press I or Escape doesn't change this command line editing mode. The Up and Down arrows do work. I don't have X-Windows access, or at least I haven't tried it.

I am ssh'ing into this machine from a MacOS machine, and the keys are so different from the Linux and MacOS shells that I am used to.

The default shell is KSH, and I switch to bash with *exec /bin/bash* at the end of .profile. My other additions to .profile which solve various issues are below:

```
export PAGER=less
export EDITOR=vi
set -o vi
```

The complete .profile is pasted here:

```
ESC=`printf "\033"`
BEL=`printf "\007"`
BS=`printf "\010"`

stty erase $BS
umask 00022

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/openwin/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
MANPATH=/usr/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man
HOSTNAME=`hostname`
export PAGER=less
if [ $0 = ksh -o $0 = -ksh ] ; then
        set -o vi
        PS1="[$LOGNAME@$HOSTNAME: \$PWD ]
$ "
        export HISTSIZE=4096
fi

case $TERM in
  sun-cmd) PS1="$ESC]l$HOSTNAME$ESC$PS1"
    ;;
  xterm)   PS1="$ESC]0;$HOSTNAME$BEL$PS1"
    ;;
  *)    ;;
esac

unset ESC BEL BS

EDITOR=vi

export PATH LOGNAME HOSTNAME MANPATH EDITOR

export EDITOR=vi
set -o vi
exec /bin/bash
```

This is .bashrc:

```
export TERM=xterm
export EDITOR=vi
set -o vi
```

Comment: The non-ascii keys generate escape codes, which are then decoded from the terminfo database. E.g. my `->` key emits `ESC [ C`, of which only the C is visible. As you are using ssh, the `TERM` variable in the SunOS system will not be set to match the Mac keyboard. You might try exporting the TERM variable in Sun to match that in Mac, although the correct terminfo may not be present. Also try using the old vi ascii commands: `k` is UP, `j` is DOWN, `h` is LEFT, `l` is RIGHT, etc. Or scp the file to Mac, edit locally, scp back to Sun.

Comment: "export TERM=xterm" It shouldn't be necessary to hardcode a terminal type like this. Ssh passes the TERM value to the remote system for terminal sessions.